# What happened to my document? Space when landscape

Tags: spacing, formatting, environments, landscape, nicematrix

I am sharing with you the code of one exercise of my homework. I need a landscape part because there is not enough space on the page for the words I wrote. However when I use the environment `landscape` there is too much space from the left to the right. Here is a picture of the situation:

[image: Error Illustration]

So it is already wrong. Can you help to identify my mistake?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PREAMBLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PAQUETES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Avoid problems with accents and special charracters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%document Format
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%Colors along the docuemnt.
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Format for mathematical assertions
\usepackage{amsthm}
%More useful symbols
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Even more useful symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
%Language of Expresions
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Format Sections
\usepackage{sectsty}
%Font for canonical sets
\usepackage{dsfont}
%Images inclusion
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Long comments
\usepackage{comment}
%Caritas
\usepackage{wasysym}
%Referencias
\usepackage{hyperref}
%Enumeración con Color
\usepackage{enumitem}
%Hoja Volteada
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLORS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,176,246}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ENTORNOS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Exercise Enviroment
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\newcounter{exercise}
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\arabic{exercise}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exercise}
    \par\medskip
    \noindent \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Exercise~\theexercise}. #1}} \rmfamily
    {\medskip}
    
%Proofs
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof:\\}}{\rightline{$\blacksquare$}}

%Mathematical Staments
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lem}[Theo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Def}[Theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Not}[Theo]{Notation}
\newtheorem{Cor}{Corollary}[Theo]
\newtheorem{Propo}[Theo]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Prope}[Theo]{Property}
\newtheorem{Obs}[Theo]{Observation}
    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%MY COMMANDS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%New
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathbb{I}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

%Renewed

\renewcommand{\sup}{\operatorname{Sup}}
\renewcommand{\inf}{\operatorname{Inf}}
\renewcommand{\limsup}{\operatorname{LimSup}}
\renewcommand{\liminf}{\operatorname{LimInf}}
\renewcommand{\min}{\operatorname{Min}}
\renewcommand{\max}{\operatorname{Max}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ESTYLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}

%Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=red
}

\urlstyle{same}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&TÍTULO&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Homework \#5\\
Analysis I (English)}}}
\author{\textcolor{blue}{\textit{Germán Felipe López Díaz}}}
\date{\textit{\textcolor{blue}{March 9\textsuperscript{th}, 2021}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%DOCUMENTO%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{exercise}{5}

\begin{exercise}
    
    \textcolor{blue}{The Fibonacci sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ is defined recursively by:
    \[a_{0} = 1 \hspace{0.5cm} a_{1} = 1 \hspace{0.5cm} a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\hspace{0.5cm}n \in \N\]
    Moreover, let $\sigma < \tau$ the solutions of $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$ and
    \[x_{n} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}, n \in \N\]}
    
    For its exercise we need some lemmas:
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L1}
        For any $n \in \N_{0}$. In Fibonacci sequence context, $a_{n} > 0$.
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{proof}
        
        \textbf{Bases Cases:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[$\star$] $\mathit{n = 0}:$ Suppose by contradiction that not. That is that $a_{0} \leq 0$. By definition $a_{0} = 1$. Therefore:
            \[1 \leq 0\]
            A contradiction! with the order of natural numbers. In conclusion it must be true that $a_{0} > 0$.
            \item[$\star$] $\mathit{n = 1}:$ Suppose by contradiction that not. That is that $a_{1} \leq 0$. By definition $a_{1} = 1$. Therefore:
            \[1 \leq 0\]
            A contradiction! with the order of natural numbers. In conclusion it must be true that $a_{1} > 0$.
        \end{itemize}
        \textbf{Inductive Step:}
        
        Suppose the result for any $k \in \N$ with $k \leq n$. It is that:
        \[\forall_{k \in \N}\left[(k \leq n) \rightarrow (a_{k} > 0)\right]\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
        We want to verify the result for $n+1$. By the recursive definition we have that:
        \[a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        By \textbf{(HI)} we have that the right side is a non negative number due to $n \leq n$ and $n-1 \leq 1$ and the addition of to non negative numbers is again a non negative number. Call it $P$:
        \[a_{n+1} = P\]
        By the Strong Induction Principle we have that the result is true for all $n \in \N_{0}$.
    \end{proof}
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L2}
        Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$, $\sigma < \tau$, solutions for the equation $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$. Then:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[(i)] $\tau - \sigma = \sqrt{5}$ 
            \item[(ii)] $\tau^{2} - \sigma^{2} = \tau - \sigma$ 
            \item[(iii)] $\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2} = 1 = \sigma^{-1}+ \sigma^{-2}$
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{proof}
            Initially by definition of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ we have the following equality:
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.1}
                \tau^{2} - \tau - 1 = 0
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.2}
                \sigma^{2} - \sigma - 1 = 0
            \end{equation}
            On the other hand, remember The Quadratic Formula:
            \[x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}\]
            We use it to solve the polynomial $x^{2} - x - 1$ using the with $a = 1$, $b = -1$ and $c = -1$:
            \[x = \frac{-(-1) \pm \sqrt{(-1)^{2} - 4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}\]
            \[x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4}}{2}\]
            \[x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\]
            According to Precalculus course we have that its polynomial has two roots:
            \[x_{1} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\hspace{1cm}x_{2} =\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\]
            Both of them are real! Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are roots of it, necesarily, we must have that:
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.3}
                \sigma = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.4}
                \tau = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
            \end{equation}
            Because $\sigma < \tau$
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[(i)] 
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                    \tau  - \sigma & = & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} - \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} & \left(\text{Equation \textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.3})} and \textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.4})}}\right)\\
                    & = & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5} -1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}& \left(\text{Subtraction of homogeneous fractions}\right)\\
                    & = & \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{2}& \left(\text{Adding similar terms}\right)\\
                    & = & \sqrt{5} & \left(\text{Canceling}\right)\\
                \end{array}\]
                \item[(ii)] Using equation $\textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.1})}$ and $\textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.2})}$ finding the quadratic term we get that:
                \[\tau^{2} = \tau + 1 \hspace{1cm}\sigma^{2} = \sigma + 1\]
                Thus we get:
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                    \tau^{2} - \sigma^{2} & = & \tau + 1 - (\sigma + 1) &\left(\text{Substraction of last equations}\right)\\
                    & = & \tau + 1 - \sigma - 1 & \left(\text{Distributing the minus}\right)\\
                    & = & \tau - \sigma & \left(\text{Adding similar terms}\right)\\ 
                \end{array}\] 
                
                \item[(iii)] Let $s$ be solution of the equation $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$. from the solution of the Quadratic Formula, that we did at the beginning, we have that $s = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. There fore we have the following equality:
                \[s^{-1} = \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}} \hspace{2cm} s^{-2} = \frac{4}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                Let´s see what is $s^{-1} + s^{-2}$:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}\]
                A common denominator is $(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}$. Thus we have that:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{2 \pm 2\sqrt{5} + 4}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                We can rewrite the expression as:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{1 \pm 2\sqrt{5} + 5}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                Notice the numerator is the same denominator but solved:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                So canceling we get:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = 1\]
                Since it is true for any solution of the equation we have what we wanted:
                \[\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2} = 1 =\sigma^{-1} + \sigma^{-2}\] 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L3}
        Let $p \in \R$. Define $a_{n} = p^{n}$. If $|p| < 1$ then, the sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}\subseteq\R$ converges to zero.
        
        \begin{proof}
            
            It is enough to verify that the sequence is bounded above and is monotonic decreasing:
            
            
            \textbf{The sequence is bounded above by $\boldsymbol{0}$: }We want to see that for any $n \in \N_{0}$ $, 0 \leq a_{n}$. Proceed by induction over $n \in \N_{0}$:
            
            \textit{Base Case: $\mathit{n = 1}$}
            
            Notice that $a_{0} = p^0 = 1$ and it clearly satisfies that:
            \[0 \leq 1\]
            So we have that $0 \leq a_{n}$
            
            \textit{Inductive Step:}
            
            Suppose the result for $n = k$. It is that:
            \[0 \leq a_{k}\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
            We want to verify the inequality for $n = k+1$ (i.e. $0 \leq a_{k+1}$)
            \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+1} & = & p^{k+1} & \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)\\
                & = & pp^{k} & \left(\text{Powers Properties}\right)\\
                & = & pa_{k} & \left(\text{$a_{k}$ definition}\right)\\
                & \geq & p0 &  \left(\textbf{(HI)}\right)\\
                & \geq & 0 & \left(\text{$0$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            So by the induction principle we have the result for any $n \in \N_{0}$. Thus $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ is bounded above by $0$.
            
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{{a_{n})_{n \in \N}}}$ is monotonically decreasing:} We want to verify that $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n}$. We proceed by induction over $n$:
            
            \textbf{Base Case:}\textit{$n = 0$}
            Notice that $a_{0 +1} = a_{1} = p$ and $a_{0} = p^{0} = 1$. Since $|p| < 1$, $-1 < p < 1$. Thus, in particular, we get that:
            \[p \leq 1\]
            Therefore $a_{1} \leq a_{0}$

            \textbf{Inductive Step:}
            
            Suppose the result for $n = k$. It is that:
            \[a_{k+1} \leq a_{k}\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
            We want to verify the inequality for $n = k+1$ (i.e. $a_{k+2} \leq a_{k+1}$)
            We have to cases: 
            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                \item $0 \leq p < 1$
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+1} & \leq & a_{k} & \left(\textbf{(HI)}\right)\\
                pa_{k+1} & \leq & pa_{k} & \left(\text{$p \geq 0$}\right)\\
                pp^{k+1}& \leq & pp^{k} & \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k}$ definition}\right)\\
                p^{k+2}& \leq & p^{k+1} &  \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
                a_{k+2}& \leq & a_{k+1} & \left(\text{$a_{k+2}$ and $a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            As we wanted!
            
            \item $1 < p < 0$ 
            \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+2} &  = & p^{k+2} & \left(\text{$a_{k+2}$ definition}\right)\\
                & = & pp^{k+1} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
                & \leq & p^{k+1} & \left(\text{$p < 0$}\right)\\
                & \leq & a_{k+1} &  \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            \end{enumerate}
            
            So by the induction principle we have the result for any $n \in \N_{0}$. Thus $a_{n +1} \leq a_{n}$.
 
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L4}
        Let $k \in \N$ and we define $x_{n} = \frac{1}{n^{k}}$ for $n \in \N$. Then $(x_{n})_{n \in \N}$ converges to zero. 
        \begin{proof}
            See Homework 4 Lemma 4.
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{blue}{(\alph*)}]
        \item \textcolor{blue}{Show that $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ does not converge in $\R$.}
        
        Suppose by contradiction that it does. So we have that for any $n \in \N$ $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{a_{n}} = r$ for some $r \in \R$. Using recursive definition  of the sequence we get that:
        \[a_{n+1} =  a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        Passing by the limit:
        \[\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n} a_{n-1}}\]
        \[\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} + \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n-1}}\]
        Using our hypothesis: 
        \[r = r + r\]
        \[r = 2r\]
        Therefore, divide both sides by $r$. It is fair because of the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L1}}:
        \[1 = 2\]
        A contradiction! It is a false statement. Thus we must have that $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ does not converge in $\R$.
        
        \item \textcolor{blue}{$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1}), n \in \N$.}
        
        We are going to demonstrate it by Strong Induction o over $n \in \N_{0}$:
        \textbf{Bases Cases:}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[\textasteriskcentered] $\mathit{n = 0}:$ Let $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{0+1} - \sigma^{0+1})$. Recall that by definition we have that $a_{0} = 1$, so it is enough to verify that $R = 1$: 
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau - \sigma)\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(i)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5}\]
                Canceling:
                \[R = 1\]
                \item[\textasteriskcentered] $\mathit{n = 1}:$ Let $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{1+1} - \sigma^{1+1})$. Recall that by definition we have that $a_{1} = 1$, so it is enough to verify that $R = 1$: 
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{2} - \sigma^{2})\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(ii)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau - \sigma)\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(i)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5}\]
                Canceling:
                \[R = 1\]
            \end{itemize}
        \textbf{Inductive Step:}
        Suppose the result for $k \in \N$ with $k \leq n$. It is that:
        \[\textbf{(HI)} \hspace{2cm} \forall_{k \in \N_{0}}{\left\{\left(k \leq n\right) \rightarrow \left[a_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{k+1} - \sigma^{k+1})\right]\right\}}\]
        We prove it for $n+1$. It is that:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})\]
        By the recursive definition of Fibonacci Sequence:
        \[a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        By \textbf{(HI)} to $n-1$ and $n$ (they are less or equal to $n$):
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n-1+1} - \sigma^{n-1+1})\]
        Use Common Factor factorization with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1} + \tau^{n} - \sigma^{n})\]
        Use Common Factor factorization with $\tau^{n+2}$ and $\sigma^{n+2}$:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\tau^{n+2}(\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2}) - \sigma^{n+2}( \sigma^{-1} + \sigma^{-2})]\]
        Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(iii)} we can change the parenthesis:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\tau^{n+2}(1) - \sigma^{n+2}(1)]\]
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})\]
        So by the Strong Induction Principle we have that for any $n \in \N_{0}$:
        \[a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1})\]
        \begin{landscape}
        \item[\textcolor{blue}{(c) }]\textcolor{blue}{$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \tau}$.}
        
        \[\begin{array}{rclr}
            \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{n}}} & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}} & \left(\text{$x_{n}$ definition}\right)  \\
            &&&\\
            & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1})}}} & \left(\text{Exercise $(b)$ formula}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\cfrac{\frac{\tau^{n+2}}{\tau^{n+2}} - \frac{\sigma^{n+2}}{\tau^{n+2}}}{\frac{\tau^{n+1}}{\tau^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\tau} - \frac{\sigma^{n+1}}{\tau^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\tau}}}} & \left(\text{Canceling and dividing by $\tau^{n+2}$ up and down}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+2}}{\frac{1}{\tau} - \frac{1}{\tau}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+1}}}} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+2}}{\frac{1}{\tau}\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+1}\right]}}} & \left(\text{Common Factor Factorization}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}{\frac{1}{\tau}\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}}} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \frac{ \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{1} - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}}{\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}{1} - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)}\right]}} & \left(\text{Limit properties}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \frac{\displaystyle{1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}}{\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\left[1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}} & \left(\text{Solving constant limits}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \frac{\displaystyle{1 - 0\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}{\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\left[1 - 0\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}} & \left(\text{Using lemmas \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(iv)} and \ref{L3}}\right)\\
            &&&\\
        \end{array}\]
        \[\begin{array}{rclr}
            \displaystyle{\lim_{n \infty}{x_{n}}} & = & \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{\tau}}} & \left(\text{0 definition}\right)\\
            &&&\\
            & = & \tau & \left(\text{Means and extremes law}\right)\\
            &&&
        \end{array}\]
        As we wanted!
        \end{landscape}
        
    \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

Comment: it's pretty weird to have a landscape environment mid list, the `\item` inside the landscape will really have lost all context on where they are supposed to indent the text.  I wrote `landscape` and a certainly never tested this:..

Comment: note `\displaystyle` does not take an argument so `\displaystyle{...}` should not have the braces, but it would be better not to use `array` here and use an environment designed for display math, such as `align`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is align. Can you help me with an example. I am pretty new on its!

Comment: see any of the examples here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/align

Comment: you really should post a more reasonable sized example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do it to give a clear idea of what I did

Comment: no you are asking people to debug what is wrong and adding packages unrelated to the problem that add thousands of lines of code does not help anyone to help you. It is easy for you to remove any packages not used in the example before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Going from

[image: a]

to here

[image: b]

it can be done using the package `nicematrix`.

Provides the command `\Block` wich works as `multicolumn` and `multirow` and also allows  using  `\\` inside the cell.

In it simplest usage `\Block{}{<content1> \\ <content2>}` creates a 1x1 cell with two separate lines.

The five lines changed in the last array code were marked as  `%<<<< changed`

This the complete code.

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PREAMBLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PAQUETES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Avoid problems with accents and special charracters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%document Format
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%Colors along the docuemnt.
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Format for mathematical assertions
\usepackage{amsthm}
%More useful symbols
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Even more useful symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
%Language of Expresions
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Format Sections
\usepackage{sectsty}
%Font for canonical sets
\usepackage{dsfont}
%Images inclusion
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Long comments
\usepackage{comment}
%Caritas
\usepackage{wasysym}
%Referencias
\usepackage{hyperref}
%Enumeración con Color
\usepackage{enumitem}
%Hoja Volteada
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLORS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,176,246}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ENTORNOS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Exercise Enviroment
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\newcounter{exercise}
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\arabic{exercise}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exercise}
    \par\medskip
    \noindent \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Exercise~\theexercise}. #1}} \rmfamily
    {\medskip}
    
%Proofs
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent\bfseries Proof:\\}}{\rightline{$\blacksquare$}}

%Mathematical Staments
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lem}[Theo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Def}[Theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Not}[Theo]{Notation}
\newtheorem{Cor}{Corollary}[Theo]
\newtheorem{Propo}[Theo]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Prope}[Theo]{Property}
\newtheorem{Obs}[Theo]{Observation}
    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%MY COMMANDS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%New
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathbb{I}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

%Renewed

\renewcommand{\sup}{\operatorname{Sup}}
\renewcommand{\inf}{\operatorname{Inf}}
\renewcommand{\limsup}{\operatorname{LimSup}}
\renewcommand{\liminf}{\operatorname{LimInf}}
\renewcommand{\min}{\operatorname{Min}}
\renewcommand{\max}{\operatorname{Max}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ESTYLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}

%Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=red
}

\urlstyle{same}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&TÍTULO&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Homework \#5\\
Analysis I (English)}}}
\author{\textcolor{blue}{\textit{Germán Felipe López Díaz}}}
\date{\textit{\textcolor{blue}{March 9\textsuperscript{th}, 2021}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%DOCUMENTO%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{exercise}{5}

\begin{exercise}
    
    \textcolor{blue}{The Fibonacci sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ is defined recursively by:
    \[a_{0} = 1 \hspace{0.5cm} a_{1} = 1 \hspace{0.5cm} a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\hspace{0.5cm}n \in \N\]
    Moreover, let $\sigma < \tau$ the solutions of $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$ and
    \[x_{n} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}, n \in \N\]}
    
    For its exercise we need some lemmas:
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L1}
        For any $n \in \N_{0}$. In Fibonacci sequence context, $a_{n} > 0$.
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{proof}
        
        \textbf{Bases Cases:}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[$\star$] $\mathit{n = 0}:$ Suppose by contradiction that not. That is that $a_{0} \leq 0$. By definition $a_{0} = 1$. Therefore:
            \[1 \leq 0\]
            A contradiction! with the order of natural numbers. In conclusion it must be true that $a_{0} > 0$.
            \item[$\star$] $\mathit{n = 1}:$ Suppose by contradiction that not. That is that $a_{1} \leq 0$. By definition $a_{1} = 1$. Therefore:
            \[1 \leq 0\]
            A contradiction! with the order of natural numbers. In conclusion it must be true that $a_{1} > 0$.
        \end{itemize}
        \textbf{Inductive Step:}
        
        Suppose the result for any $k \in \N$ with $k \leq n$. It is that:
        \[\forall_{k \in \N}\left[(k \leq n) \rightarrow (a_{k} > 0)\right]\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
        We want to verify the result for $n+1$. By the recursive definition we have that:
        \[a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        By \textbf{(HI)} we have that the right side is a non negative number due to $n \leq n$ and $n-1 \leq 1$ and the addition of to non negative numbers is again a non negative number. Call it $P$:
        \[a_{n+1} = P\]
        By the Strong Induction Principle we have that the result is true for all $n \in \N_{0}$.
    \end{proof}
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L2}
        Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$, $\sigma < \tau$, solutions for the equation $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$. Then:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[(i)] $\tau - \sigma = \sqrt{5}$ 
            \item[(ii)] $\tau^{2} - \sigma^{2} = \tau - \sigma$ 
            \item[(iii)] $\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2} = 1 = \sigma^{-1}+ \sigma^{-2}$
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{proof}
            Initially by definition of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ we have the following equality:
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.1}
                \tau^{2} - \tau - 1 = 0
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.2}
                \sigma^{2} - \sigma - 1 = 0
            \end{equation}
            On the other hand, remember The Quadratic Formula:
            \[x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}\]
            We use it to solve the polynomial $x^{2} - x - 1$ using the with $a = 1$, $b = -1$ and $c = -1$:
            \[x = \frac{-(-1) \pm \sqrt{(-1)^{2} - 4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}\]
            \[x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4}}{2}\]
            \[x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\]
            According to Precalculus course we have that its polynomial has two roots:
            \[x_{1} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\hspace{1cm}x_{2} =\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\]
            Both of them are real! Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are roots of it, necesarily, we must have that:
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.3}
                \sigma = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
                \label{Eq1.4}
                \tau = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
            \end{equation}
            Because $\sigma < \tau$
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[(i)] 
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                    \tau  - \sigma & = & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} - \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} & \left(\text{Equation \textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.3})} and \textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.4})}}\right)\\
                    & = & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5} -1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}& \left(\text{Subtraction of homogeneous fractions}\right)\\
                    & = & \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{2}& \left(\text{Adding similar terms}\right)\\
                    & = & \sqrt{5} & \left(\text{Canceling}\right)\\
                \end{array}\]
                \item[(ii)] Using equation $\textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.1})}$ and $\textcolor{red}{(\ref{Eq1.2})}$ finding the quadratic term we get that:
                \[\tau^{2} = \tau + 1 \hspace{1cm}\sigma^{2} = \sigma + 1\]
                Thus we get:
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                    \tau^{2} - \sigma^{2} & = & \tau + 1 - (\sigma + 1) &\left(\text{Substraction of last equations}\right)\\
                    & = & \tau + 1 - \sigma - 1 & \left(\text{Distributing the minus}\right)\\
                    & = & \tau - \sigma & \left(\text{Adding similar terms}\right)\\ 
                \end{array}\] 
                
                \item[(iii)] Let $s$ be solution of the equation $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$. from the solution of the Quadratic Formula, that we did at the beginning, we have that $s = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. There fore we have the following equality:
                \[s^{-1} = \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}} \hspace{2cm} s^{-2} = \frac{4}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                Let´s see what is $s^{-1} + s^{-2}$:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}\]
                A common denominator is $(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}$. Thus we have that:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{2 \pm 2\sqrt{5} + 4}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                We can rewrite the expression as:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{1 \pm 2\sqrt{5} + 5}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                Notice the numerator is the same denominator but solved:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = \frac{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})^{2}}\]
                So canceling we get:
                \[s^{-1} + s^{-2} = 1\]
                Since it is true for any solution of the equation we have what we wanted:
                \[\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2} = 1 =\sigma^{-1} + \sigma^{-2}\] 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L3}
        Let $p \in \R$. Define $a_{n} = p^{n}$. If $|p| < 1$ then, the sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}\subseteq\R$ converges to zero.
        
        \begin{proof}
            
            It is enough to verify that the sequence is bounded above and is monotonic decreasing:
            
            
            \textbf{The sequence is bounded above by $\boldsymbol{0}$: }We want to see that for any $n \in \N_{0}$ $, 0 \leq a_{n}$. Proceed by induction over $n \in \N_{0}$:
            
            \textit{Base Case: $\mathit{n = 1}$}
            
            Notice that $a_{0} = p^0 = 1$ and it clearly satisfies that:
            \[0 \leq 1\]
            So we have that $0 \leq a_{n}$
            
            \textit{Inductive Step:}
            
            Suppose the result for $n = k$. It is that:
            \[0 \leq a_{k}\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
            We want to verify the inequality for $n = k+1$ (i.e. $0 \leq a_{k+1}$)
            \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+1} & = & p^{k+1} & \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)\\
                & = & pp^{k} & \left(\text{Powers Properties}\right)\\
                & = & pa_{k} & \left(\text{$a_{k}$ definition}\right)\\
                & \geq & p0 &  \left(\textbf{(HI)}\right)\\
                & \geq & 0 & \left(\text{$0$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            So by the induction principle we have the result for any $n \in \N_{0}$. Thus $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ is bounded above by $0$.
            
            \textbf{$\boldsymbol{{a_{n})_{n \in \N}}}$ is monotonically decreasing:} We want to verify that $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n}$. We proceed by induction over $n$:
            
            \textbf{Base Case:}\textit{$n = 0$}
            Notice that $a_{0 +1} = a_{1} = p$ and $a_{0} = p^{0} = 1$. Since $|p| < 1$, $-1 < p < 1$. Thus, in particular, we get that:
            \[p \leq 1\]
            Therefore $a_{1} \leq a_{0}$

            \textbf{Inductive Step:}
            
            Suppose the result for $n = k$. It is that:
            \[a_{k+1} \leq a_{k}\hspace{2cm}\textbf{(HI)}\]
            We want to verify the inequality for $n = k+1$ (i.e. $a_{k+2} \leq a_{k+1}$)
            We have to cases: 
            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                \item $0 \leq p < 1$
                \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+1} & \leq & a_{k} & \left(\textbf{(HI)}\right)\\
                pa_{k+1} & \leq & pa_{k} & \left(\text{$p \geq 0$}\right)\\
                pp^{k+1}& \leq & pp^{k} & \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k}$ definition}\right)\\
                p^{k+2}& \leq & p^{k+1} &  \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
                a_{k+2}& \leq & a_{k+1} & \left(\text{$a_{k+2}$ and $a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            As we wanted!
            
            \item $1 < p < 0$ 
            \[\begin{array}{rclr}
                a_{k+2} &  = & p^{k+2} & \left(\text{$a_{k+2}$ definition}\right)\\
                & = & pp^{k+1} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
                & \leq & p^{k+1} & \left(\text{$p < 0$}\right)\\
                & \leq & a_{k+1} &  \left(\text{$a_{k+1}$ definition}\right)
            \end{array}\]
            \end{enumerate}
            
            So by the induction principle we have the result for any $n \in \N_{0}$. Thus $a_{n +1} \leq a_{n}$.
 
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{Lem}
        \label{L4}
        Let $k \in \N$ and we define $x_{n} = \frac{1}{n^{k}}$ for $n \in \N$. Then $(x_{n})_{n \in \N}$ converges to zero. 
        \begin{proof}
            See Homework 4 Lemma 4.
        \end{proof}
    \end{Lem}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{blue}{(\alph*)}]
        \item \textcolor{blue}{Show that $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ does not converge in $\R$.}
        
        Suppose by contradiction that it does. So we have that for any $n \in \N$ $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{a_{n}} = r$ for some $r \in \R$. Using recursive definition  of the sequence we get that:
        \[a_{n+1} =  a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        Passing by the limit:
        \[\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n} a_{n-1}}\]
        \[\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}} + \lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n-1}}\]
        Using our hypothesis: 
        \[r = r + r\]
        \[r = 2r\]
        Therefore, divide both sides by $r$. It is fair because of the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L1}}:
        \[1 = 2\]
        A contradiction! It is a false statement. Thus we must have that $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ does not converge in $\R$.
        
        \item \textcolor{blue}{$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1}), n \in \N$.}
        
        We are going to demonstrate it by Strong Induction o over $n \in \N_{0}$:
        \textbf{Bases Cases:}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[\textasteriskcentered] $\mathit{n = 0}:$ Let $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{0+1} - \sigma^{0+1})$. Recall that by definition we have that $a_{0} = 1$, so it is enough to verify that $R = 1$: 
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau - \sigma)\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(i)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5}\]
                Canceling:
                \[R = 1\]
                \item[\textasteriskcentered] $\mathit{n = 1}:$ Let $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{1+1} - \sigma^{1+1})$. Recall that by definition we have that $a_{1} = 1$, so it is enough to verify that $R = 1$: 
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{2} - \sigma^{2})\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(ii)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau - \sigma)\]
                Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(i)} we get that:
                \[R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5}\]
                Canceling:
                \[R = 1\]
            \end{itemize}
        \textbf{Inductive Step:}
        Suppose the result for $k \in \N$ with $k \leq n$. It is that:
        \[\textbf{(HI)} \hspace{2cm} \forall_{k \in \N_{0}}{\left\{\left(k \leq n\right) \rightarrow \left[a_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{k+1} - \sigma^{k+1})\right]\right\}}\]
        We prove it for $n+1$. It is that:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})\]
        By the recursive definition of Fibonacci Sequence:
        \[a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1}\]
        By \textbf{(HI)} to $n-1$ and $n$ (they are less or equal to $n$):
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n-1+1} - \sigma^{n-1+1})\]
        Use Common Factor factorization with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1} + \tau^{n} - \sigma^{n})\]
        Use Common Factor factorization with $\tau^{n+2}$ and $\sigma^{n+2}$:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\tau^{n+2}(\tau^{-1} + \tau^{-2}) - \sigma^{n+2}( \sigma^{-1} + \sigma^{-2})]\]
        Using the lemma \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(iii)} we can change the parenthesis:
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\tau^{n+2}(1) - \sigma^{n+2}(1)]\]
        \[a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})\]
        So by the Strong Induction Principle we have that for any $n \in \N_{0}$:
        \[a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1})\]
%        \begin{landscape}
        \item[\textcolor{blue}{(c) }]\textcolor{blue}{$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \tau}$.}
   % <<<<<<<< changed from here      
  \[\begin{NiceArray}{rclr} %<<<< changed
  \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{n}}} & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}} & \left(\text{$x_{n}$ definition}\right)  \\
  &&&\\
  & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+2} - \sigma^{n+2})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\tau^{n+1} - \sigma^{n+1})}}} & \left(\text{Exercise $(b)$ formula}\right)\\
  &&&\\
  & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\cfrac{\frac{\tau^{n+2}}{\tau^{n+2}} - \frac{\sigma^{n+2}}{\tau^{n+2}}}{\frac{\tau^{n+1}}{\tau^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\tau} - \frac{\sigma^{n+1}}{\tau^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\tau}}}} & \Block{}{\text{(Canceling and dividing by} \\ \text{$\tau^{n+2}$} \text{\, up and down)}}\\ %<<<< changed
  &&&\\
  & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+2}}{\frac{1}{\tau} - \frac{1}{\tau}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+1}}}} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
  &&&\\
  & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+2}}{\frac{1}{\tau}\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n+1}\right]}}} & \Block{}{\text{(Common Factor}\\\text{ Factorization)}}\\%<<<< changed
  &&&\\
  & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}{\frac{1}{\tau}\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}}} & \left(\text{Power properties}\right)\\
  &&&\\
  & = & \frac{ \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{1} - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}}{\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}{1} - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)}\right]}} & \left(\text{Limit properties}\right)\\
  &&&\\
  & = & \frac{\displaystyle{1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}}{\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\left[1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{n}}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}} & \left(\text{Solving constant limits}\right)\\
  &&&\\
  & = & \frac{\displaystyle{1 - 0\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)^{2}}}{\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\left[1 - 0\left(\frac{\sigma}{\tau}\right)\right]}} & \Block{}{ \text{Using lemmas} \\ \text{ \textcolor{red}{\ref{L2}.(iv)}  and \ref{L3}.)}}\\%<<<< changed
  &&&\\   
    % \[\begin{array}{rclr}
  & = & \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{\tau}}} & \left(\text{0 definition}\right)\\%<<<< changed
  &&&\\
    & = & \tau & \left(\text{Means and extremes law}\right)\\
  &&& \\
    % \end{array}\]
 \end{NiceArray}\]        % <<<<<<<< changed to here  
     
        As we wanted!
%        \end{landscape}
        
    \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks my dear! I finally could send my homework